# how to perform reduce(hcat, <Vector{Vector}>) by TensorCast.jl?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to do the following [via `TensorCast.jl`](https://mcabbott.github.io/TensorCast.jl/dev/reduce/#Reductions) as well?

```
#This is an object of type Vector{Vector{Float64}}
julia> a = [rand(5) for i=1:5];

julia> reduce(hcat, a)
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0678613  0.266194   0.183221   0.485462  0.873282
 0.735101   0.925276   0.956102   0.333281  0.885147
 0.323555   0.74204    0.135538   0.26123   0.261068
 0.81847    0.917006   0.0118195  0.295497  0.712431
 0.420139   0.0197552  0.0617039  0.157477  0.500931
```

I tried something super silly, I guess ():

```
julia> @reduce b := hcat(a)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching guesstarget(::Nothing, ::Vector{Any}, ::Vector{Any})
Closest candidates are:
  guesstarget(::Expr, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\TensorCast\mQB8h\src\macro.jl:1330
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
@cast b[j,i] := a[i][j]
```

Example:

```
julia> a = [rand(3) for _ in 1:2]
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.20012490537057803, 0.0365551498875093, 0.02494737196890595]
 [0.6563493855249903, 0.181706254856571, 0.29210798163726615]

julia> @cast b[j,i] := a[i][j]
3×2 lazystack(::Vector{Vector{Float64}}) with eltype Float64:
 0.200125   0.656349
 0.0365551  0.181706
 0.0249474  0.292108

julia> (@cast b[j,i] := a[i][j]) ==  reduce(hcat, a)
true
```

#### Exaplanation

The variables `i` and `j` are used by `@cast` to define the matrix layout - we have a `Vector` of `Vectors` and hence on the right side you can see `a[i][j]`, `:=` defines a new `Matrix` and `b[j,i]` says where the corresponding `i` and `j` elements should go. Note that you do not declare `i` and `j` variables - this is handled by the macro.

Finally, note that if you want the result to be materialized to an actual matrix (rather than a lazystack) you can next do `collect(b)`

Comment: Not sure but don't you get the transpose of `reduce(hcat, a)` if you don't flip `i` and `j` after the `:=`?

Comment: to be clear I mean, wouldn't `reduce(hcat, a)` be `3x2`?

Comment: Thanks! But, Please, don't rush. `julia> reduce(hcat, a) == b
false`. You should write `b[j, i] := ...`. And, can you please explain about the meaning of `[i][j]`?

Comment: I added explanation and transposed the Matrix so now it is OK and matches `reduce(hcat, a)`